# Professor palin not unlocked?

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

In the painful quest to palin, i just decided to take a 5k ly straight line trip. I have achieved the distance after 3 and a half hours travel time.

Before i make the return trip, i would like to wait until Palin is unlocked.

I can confirm i have met the criteria from Qwent, i can also say i have just achieved 5kly from start. No unlocking nor invite? 
Is this a waiting game? Or shall i be safe for the return trip?

Comment: 3.5 hours is way too long for a 5-kylie rush, unless you're sightseeing along the way. If you need to do long trips like that again, I strongly suggest getting an AspX or 'Conda and building it out for maximum jump range.

Comment: I ran into this again the other day with Lei Cheung. At least on the Xbox, this seems to be a relatively consistent issue with the Engineers. You meet the criteria to move on to the next step in unlocking, but the next step doesn't actually trigger until a re-log.

Answer (score 2):

***Have you tried turning it off and back on again?***

Seriously, a lot of things like this seem to require logging out and back in to trigger them. I'm pretty sure I had to do this at certain points in unlocking Farseer and Martuuk. More recently, I had to do it to activate my Sol Permit - despite having received the message saying that I had it, it wouldn't work until a re-log.

Comment: As silly as it is- logging out and back in triggered the invites from Palin and Sedesi. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the right panel statistics show max distance from start as over 5000 LY, you should be fine. Seems to take a few jumps after that for the invite to show up.

Also note: you don’t have to survive; you can go 5000LY from start, self-destruct and still get the invite.

Comment: Im still out in the deep, i still have had no unlock. I have however found an uncharted system

Comment: And you got Qwent to grade 4?

Comment: Indeed. The actual 5kly is not checked off, despite it stating 5k/5k

Comment: @DarylGill could there be a rounding issue?